# How to query Timestamp field in firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm storing serverTimestamp with every record in the firebase while creating and modifying.

For example:

```
{
  "name": "Something",
  "timestamp": serverTimestamp() 
}
```

This will be stored as a `Timestamp` object which is very different from the `Date` object.

I'm trying query the records which are created after a given time.

I've tried querying by follow methods.

Method1: Query by milliseconds

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('accounts')
        .where("lastModified", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 1692690348)
        .get(const GetOptions(source: Source.server))
```

Method2: Query by Timestamp object

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('accounts')
        .where("lastModified", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now()))
        .get(const GetOptions(source: Source.server))
```

Method3: Query by DateTime object

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('accounts')
        .where("lastModified", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: DateTime.now())
        .get(const GetOptions(source: Source.server))
```

None of these methods didn't retrieve any result. Is there anyway we can query firestore with field containing serverTimestamp?

Comment: You should query against `lastModified` directly, not `lastModified.seconds`.